# Primary bladder neck obstruction treatment or cure

Tags: urology

What are primary bladder neck obstruction treatments or cures besides alphablockers or bladder neck incision?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is not much that can be done other than what you have mentioned.

The present guidelines for the management would include watchful waiting, medical (alpha blockers) or surgical (trans urethral bladder neck incision or resection). However, the present literature lack significant amount of randomized controlled trials that would provide reliable evidence regarding the efficacy of these treatment options. Existing reports provide contradicting results as well. Even though there are [success stories](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23412123) of complete cure by the trans urethral bladder neck resection, this still remains to be a topic where further exploration needs to be done regarding the natural history of the disease, and possible treatment modalities.

References : [Primary Bladder Neck Obstruction in Men and Women](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1477631/)